# Web scraping multiple google scholar pages in python

Tags: python, selenium, for-loop, web-scraping, google-scholar

I want to scrape multiple Google scholar user profiles - publications, journals, citations etc. I have already written the python code for scraping a user profile given the url. Now, suppose I have 100 names and the corresponding urls in an excel file like this.

```
name       link

Autor      https://scholar.google.com/citations?user=cp-8uaAAAAAJ&hl=en
Dorn       https://scholar.google.com/citations?user=w3Dri00AAAAJ&hl=en
Hanson     https://scholar.google.com/citations?user=nMtHiQsAAAAJ&hl=en
Borjas     https://scholar.google.com/citations?user=Patm-BEAAAAJ&hl=en
....
```

My question is can I read the 'link' column of this file and write a for loop for the urls so that I can scrape each of these profiles and append the results in the same file. I seems a bit far fetched but I hope there is a way to do so. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pandas.read_csv()` to read a specific file from a csv. For example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
arr = []
link_col = df['link']
for i in link_col:
    arr.append(i);
   
print(arr)
```

This would allow you extract only the link column and append each value into your array. If you'd like you learn more, you can refer to [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/index.html#getting-started).

Answer (score 0):

I hope it is not too advanced for you

1 Create a class for your pages

```
class Pages:
    def __init__(self, name=None, link=None):
        self.name = name
        self.link = link
```

2 Create `pages` list

```
pages = []
```

3 Find rows locator, like:

```
rows = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("your_selector")
```

rows number must be the same as the number of rows in you table. For example, the you have to items in the list, the `rows` number will be 20.

4 Get each row value:

```
for row in rows:
    name = row.find_element_by_css_selector("here is a unique selector for each data field for name").text
    link = row.find_element_by_css_selector("here is a unique selector for each data field for link").text
```

5 Create pages object:

```
page = Page(name=name,link=link)
```

6 Put all rows to the list:

```
pages.append(page)
```

#### Result

A list of pages (object `page`) where the first row will be accessible with `pages[0]`, second with `pages[1]` and so on.

**P.S**
If you are having trouble with selectors, as them as different questions.
I think I explained the concept to you, so you will be able to start.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I am just a beginner in python. But, I will try this and see..thanks!

Comment: It will take some time. One more option, that should be easier is to use a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

To read data from an Excel file you can use `pandas` [`read_excel()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) method like so:

```py
# https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html
authors_df = pd.read_excel("google_scholar_scrape_multiple_authors.xlsx", sheet_name="authors") # sheet_name is optional in this case

print(authors_df["author_link"])

'''
0    https://scholar.google.com/citations?hl=en&use...
1    https://scholar.google.com/citations?hl=en&use...
2    https://scholar.google.com/citations?hl=en&use...
3    https://scholar.google.com/citations?hl=en&use...
4    https://scholar.google.com/citations?hl=en&use...
Name: author_link, dtype: object
'''

print(authors_df)

'''
         author_name                                        author_link
0      Masatoshi Nei  https://scholar.google.com/citations?hl=en&use...
1  Ulrich K. Laemmli  https://scholar.google.com/citations?hl=en&use...
2         Gene Myers  https://scholar.google.com/citations?hl=en&use...
3       Sudhir Kumar  https://scholar.google.com/citations?hl=en&use...
4    Irving Weissman  https://scholar.google.com/citations?hl=en&use...
'''
```

---

To scrape from multiple authors you can use a `for` loop to iterate over `["author_link"]` and extract desired data using [`beautifulsoup`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/), [`lxml`](https://lxml.de/), and [`requests`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/) libraries.

---

[Code and full example in the online IDE](https://replit.com/@DimitryZub1/web-scraping-multiple-google-scholar-pages-in-python#main.py):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, lxml
import pandas as pd

# https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#custom-headers
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582",
}

# https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html
authors_df = pd.read_excel("google_scholar_scrape_multiple_authors.xlsx", sheet_name="authors") # sheet_name is optional in this case

# to_list() returns a list of author links so we can iterate over them
for author_link in authors_df["author_link"].to_list():
    html = requests.get(author_link, headers=headers, timeout=30)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, "lxml")

    print(f"Currently extracting: {soup.select_one('#gsc_prf_in').text}")

    author_email = soup.select_one("#gsc_prf_ivh").text
    author_image = f'https://scholar.google.com{soup.select_one("#gsc_prf_pup-img")["src"]}'

    print(author_image, f"Author email: {author_email}", sep="\n")
     
    # iterating over container with all needed data by accessing the right CSS selector
    # have a look at SelectorGadget Chrome extension to easily grab CSS selectors
    for article in soup.select("#gsc_a_b .gsc_a_t"):
        article_title = article.select_one(".gsc_a_at").text
        article_link = f'https://scholar.google.com{article.select_one(".gsc_a_at")["href"]}'
        article_authors = article.select_one(".gsc_a_at+ .gs_gray").text
        article_publication = article.select_one(".gs_gray+ .gs_gray").text

        print(article_title, article_link, article_authors, article_publication, sep="\n")

    print("-" * 15)


# part of the output:
'''
Currently extracting: Masatoshi Nei
https://scholar.google.comhttps://scholar.googleusercontent.com/citations?view_op=view_photo&user=VxOmZDgAAAAJ&citpid=3
Author email: Verified email at temple.edu
The neighbor-joining method: a new method for reconstructing phylogenetic trees.
https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=view_citation&hl=en&user=VxOmZDgAAAAJ&citation_for_view=VxOmZDgAAAAJ:u5HHmVD_uO8C
N Saitou, M Nei
Molecular biology and evolution 4 (4), 406-425, 1987

... other results

---------------
Currently extracting: Irving Weissman
https://scholar.google.com/citations/images/avatar_scholar_128.png
Author email: Verified email at stanford.edu
Stem cells, cancer, and cancer stem cells
https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=view_citation&hl=en&user=Y66bJgUAAAAJ&citation_for_view=Y66bJgUAAAAJ:u5HHmVD_uO8C
T Reya, SJ Morrison, MF Clarke, IL Weissman
nature 414 (6859), 105-111, 2001
'''
```

---

Alternatively, you can achieve the same thing using [Google Scholar Author API](https://serpapi.com/google-scholar-author-api) from SeprApi. It's a paid API with a free plan.

Essentially, you only need to grab the data you want from the received dictionary without the need to figure out what selectors to use in order to scrape the proper data, how to bypass blocks from Google, how to increase the number of requests.

Example code to integrate:

```py
import re
import pandas as pd
from serpapi import GoogleSearch

authors_df = pd.read_excel("google_scholar_scrape_multiple_authors.xlsx", sheet_name="authors")  # sheet_name is optional in this case

for author in authors_df["author_link"].to_list():
    params = {
        "api_key": "YOUR_API_KEY",
        "engine": "google_scholar_author",
        "hl": "en",
        # using basic regular expression to grab user ID from the passed URL 
        "author_id": re.search(r"user=(.*)", author).group(1)  # -> VxOmZDgAAAAJ, unique author ID from the URL
    }

    search = GoogleSearch(params)
    results = search.get_dict()

    print(f"Extracting data from: {results['author']['name']}\n"
          f"Author info: {results['author']}\n\n"
          f"Author articles:\n{results['articles']}\n")

# part of the output:
'''
Extracting data from: Masatoshi Nei
Author info: {'name': 'Masatoshi Nei', 'affiliations': 'Laura Carnell Professor of Biology, Temple University', 'email': 'Verified email at temple.edu', 'interests': [{'title': 'Evolution', 'link': 'https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=search_authors&hl=en&mauthors=label:evolution', 'serpapi_link': 'https://serpapi.com/search.json?engine=google_scholar_profiles&hl=en&mauthors=label%3Aevolution'}, {'title': 'Evolutionary biology', 'link': 'https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=search_authors&hl=en&mauthors=label:evolutionary_biology', 'serpapi_link': 'https://serpapi.com/search.json?engine=google_scholar_profiles&hl=en&mauthors=label%3Aevolutionary_biology'}, {'title': 'Molecular evolution', 'link': 'https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=search_authors&hl=en&mauthors=label:molecular_evolution', 'serpapi_link': 'https://serpapi.com/search.json?engine=google_scholar_profiles&hl=en&mauthors=label%3Amolecular_evolution'}, {'title': 'Population genetics', 'link': 'https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=search_authors&hl=en&mauthors=label:population_genetics', 'serpapi_link': 'https://serpapi.com/search.json?engine=google_scholar_profiles&hl=en&mauthors=label%3Apopulation_genetics'}, {'title': 'Phylogenetics', 'link': 'https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=search_authors&hl=en&mauthors=label:phylogenetics', 'serpapi_link': 'https://serpapi.com/search.json?engine=google_scholar_profiles&hl=en&mauthors=label%3Aphylogenetics'}], 'thumbnail': 'https://scholar.googleusercontent.com/citations?view_op=view_photo&user=VxOmZDgAAAAJ&citpid=3'}

Author articles:
[{'title': 'The neighbor-joining method: a new method for reconstructing phylogenetic trees.', 'link': 'https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=view_citation&hl=en&user=VxOmZDgAAAAJ&citation_for_view=VxOmZDgAAAAJ:u5HHmVD_uO8C', 'citation_id': 'VxOmZDgAAAAJ:u5HHmVD_uO8C', 'authors': 'N Saitou, M Nei', 'publication': 'Molecular biology and evolution 4 (4), 406-425, 1987', 'cited_by': {'value': 64841, 'link': 'https://scholar.google.com/scholar?oi=bibs&hl=en&cites=7672721046330422437,346314157833338191', 'serpapi_link': 'https://serpapi.com/search.json?cites=7672721046330422437%2C346314157833338191&engine=google_scholar&hl=en', 'cites_id': '7672721046330422437,346314157833338191'}, 'year': '1987'}, {'title': 'MEGA5: molecular evolutionary genetics analysis using maximum likelihood, evolutionary distance, and maximum parsimony methods', 'link': 'https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=view_citation&hl=en&user=VxOmZDgAAAAJ&citation_for_view=VxOmZDgAAAAJ:Tyk-4Ss8FVUC', 'citation_id': 'VxOmZDgAAAAJ:Tyk-4Ss8FVUC', 'authors': 'K Tamura, D Peterson, N Peterson, G Stecher, M Nei, S Kumar', 'publication': 'Molecular biology and evolution 28 (10), 2731-2739, 2011', 'cited_by': {'value': 44316, 'link': 'https://scholar.google.com/scholar?oi=bibs&hl=en&cites=5624029996178252455,5910675136328950108,13537318717249213469', 'serpapi_link': 'https://serpapi.com/search.json?cites=5624029996178252455%2C5910675136328950108%2C13537318717249213469&engine=google_scholar&hl=en', 'cites_id': '5624029996178252455,5910675136328950108,13537318717249213469'}, 'year': '2011'}, {'title': 'MEGA6: molecular evolutionary genetics analysis version 6.0', 'link': 'https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=view_citation&hl=en&user=VxOmZDgAAAAJ&citation_for_view=VxOmZDgAAAAJ:qmtmRrLr0tkC', 'citation_id': 'VxOmZDgAAAAJ:qmtmRrLr0tkC', 'authors': 'K Tamura, G Stecher, D Peterson, A Filipski, S Kumar', 'publication': 'Molecular biology and evolution 30 (12), 2725-2729, 2013', 'cited_by': {'value': 40558, 'link': 'https://scholar.google.com/scholar?oi=bibs&hl=en&cites=5258359186493639031', 'serpapi_link': 'https://serpapi.com/search.json?cites=5258359186493639031&engine=google_scholar&hl=en', 'cites_id': '5258359186493639031'}, 'year': '2013'}, {'title': 'MEGA4: molecular evolutionary genetics analysis (MEGA) software version 4.0', 'link': 'https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=view_citation&hl=en&user=VxOmZDgAAAAJ&citation_for_view=VxOmZDgAAAAJ:u-x6o8ySG0sC', 'citation_id': 'VxOmZDgAAAAJ:u-x6o8ySG0sC', 'authors': 'K Tamura, J Dudley, M Nei, S Kumar', 'publication': 'Molecular biology and evolution 24 (8), 1596-1599, 2007', 'cited_by': {'value': 34245, 'link': 'https://scholar.google.com/scholar?oi=bibs&hl=en&cites=8480751610153565117', 'serpapi_link': 'https://serpapi.com/search.json?cites=8480751610153565117&engine=google_scholar&hl=en', 'cites_id': '8480751610153565117'}, 'year': '2007'}, {'title': 'Molecular evolutionary genetics', 'link': 'https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=view_citation&hl=en&user=VxOmZDgAAAAJ&citation_for_view=VxOmZDgAAAAJ:d1gkVwhDpl0C', 'citation_id': 'VxOmZDgAAAAJ:d1gkVwhDpl0C', 'authors': 'M Nei', 'publication': 'Columbia university press, 1987', 'cited_by': {'value': 20704, 'link': 'https://scholar.google.com/scholar?oi=bibs&hl=en&cites=7660515423132980153', 'serpapi_link': 'https://serpapi.com/search.json?cites=7660515423132980153&engine=google_scholar&hl=en', 'cites_id': '7660515423132980153'}, 'year': '1987'}, {'title': 'MEGA2: molecular evolutionary genetics analysis software', 'link': 'https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=view_citation&hl=en&user=VxOmZDgAAAAJ&citation_for_view=VxOmZDgAAAAJ:IjCSPb-OGe4C', 'citation_id': 'VxOmZDgAAAAJ:IjCSPb-OGe4C', 'authors': 'S Kumar, K Tamura, IB Jakobsen, M Nei', 'publication': 'Bioinformatics 17 (12), 1244-1245, 2001', 'cited_by': {'value': 16078, 'link': 'https://scholar.google.com/scholar?oi=bibs&hl=en&cites=14171206204658643394,531426008085525562,5869149036159079676,8067244568899724142,12929609819447339488,15783386726452728786', 'serpapi_link': 'https://serpapi.com/search.json?cites=14171206204658643394%2C531426008085525562%2C5869149036159079676%2C8067244568899724142%2C12929609819447339488%2C15783386726452728786&engine=google_scholar&hl=en', 'cites_id': '14171206204658643394,531426008085525562,5869149036159079676,8067244568899724142,12929609819447339488,15783386726452728786'}, 'year': '2001'}, {'title': 'Estimation of average heterozygosity and genetic distance from a small number of individuals', 'link': 'https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=view_citation&hl=en&user=VxOmZDgAAAAJ&citation_for_view=VxOmZDgAAAAJ:2osOgNQ5qMEC', 'citation_id': 'VxOmZDgAAAAJ:2osOgNQ5qMEC', 'authors': 'M Nei', 'publication': 'Genetics 89 (3), 583-590, 1978', 'cited_by': {'value': 14504, 'link': 'https://scholar.google.com/scholar?oi=bibs&hl=en&cites=11038674224870321151', 'serpapi_link': 'https://serpapi.com/search.json?cites=11038674224870321151&engine=google_scholar&hl=en', 'cites_id': '11038674224870321151'}, 'year': '1978'}, {'title': 'MEGA3: integrated software for molecular evolutionary genetics analysis and sequence alignment', 'link': 'https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=view_citation&hl=en&user=VxOmZDgAAAAJ&citation_for_view=VxOmZDgAAAAJ:9yKSN-GCB0IC', 'citation_id': 'VxOmZDgAAAAJ:9yKSN-GCB0IC', 'authors': 'S Kumar, K Tamura, M Nei', 'publication': 'Briefings in bioinformatics 5 (2), 150-163, 2004', 'cited_by': {'value': 14403, 'link': 'https://scholar.google.com/scholar?oi=bibs&hl=en&cites=10013295782066828040,15148316572039251274', 'serpapi_link': 'https://serpapi.com/search.json?cites=10013295782066828040%2C15148316572039251274&engine=google_scholar&hl=en', 'cites_id': '10013295782066828040,15148316572039251274'}, 'year': '2004'}, {'title': 'Mathematical model for studying genetic variation in terms of restriction endonucleases', 'link': 'https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=view_citation&hl=en&user=VxOmZDgAAAAJ&citation_for_view=VxOmZDgAAAAJ:qjMakFHDy7sC', 'citation_id': 'VxOmZDgAAAAJ:qjMakFHDy7sC', 'authors': 'M Nei, WH Li', 'publication': 'Proceedings of the National Academy of Sciences 76 (10), 5269-5273, 1979', 'cited_by': {'value': 13619, 'link': 'https://scholar.google.com/scholar?oi=bibs&hl=en&cites=5179626164554275201,1942230974501958280', 'serpapi_link': 'https://serpapi.com/search.json?cites=5179626164554275201%2C1942230974501958280&engine=google_scholar&hl=en', 'cites_id': '5179626164554275201,1942230974501958280'}, 'year': '1979'}, {'title': 'Genetic distance between populations', 'link': 'https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=view_citation&hl=en&user=VxOmZDgAAAAJ&citation_for_view=VxOmZDgAAAAJ:UeHWp8X0CEIC', 'citation_id': 'VxOmZDgAAAAJ:UeHWp8X0CEIC', 'authors': 'M Nei', 'publication': 'The American Naturalist 106 (949), 283-292, 1972', 'cited_by': {'value': 12980, 'link': 'https://scholar.google.com/scholar?oi=bibs&hl=en&cites=4154924214026252226,7115074001272219295', 'serpapi_link': 'https://serpapi.com/search.json?cites=4154924214026252226%2C7115074001272219295&engine=google_scholar&hl=en', 'cites_id': '4154924214026252226,7115074001272219295'}, 'year': '1972'}, {'title': 'Estimation of the number of nucleotide substitutions in the control region of mitochondrial DNA in humans and chimpanzees.', 'link': 'https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=view_citation&hl=en&user=VxOmZDgAAAAJ&citation_for_view=VxOmZDgAAAAJ:Y0pCki6q_DkC', 'citation_id': 'VxOmZDgAAAAJ:Y0pCki6q_DkC', 'authors': 'K Tamura, M Nei', 'publication': 'Molecular biology and evolution 10 (3), 512-526, 1993', 'cited_by': {'value': 11093, 'link': 'https://scholar.google.com/scholar?oi=bibs&hl=en&cites=13509507708085673250', 'serpapi_link': 'https://serpapi.com/search.json?cites=13509507708085673250&engine=google_scholar&hl=en', 'cites_id': '13509507708085673250'}, 'year': '1993'}, {'title': 'Analysis of gene diversity in subdivided populations', 'link': 'https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=view_citation&hl=en&user=VxOmZDgAAAAJ&citation_for_view=VxOmZDgAAAAJ:zYLM7Y9cAGgC', 'citation_id': 'VxOmZDgAAAAJ:zYLM7Y9cAGgC', 'authors': 'M Nei', 'publication': 'Proceedings of the national academy of sciences 70 (12), 3321-3323, 1973', 'cited_by': {'value': 10714, 'link': 'https://scholar.google.com/scholar?oi=bibs&hl=en&cites=11712109356391350421', 'serpapi_link': 'https://serpapi.com/search.json?cites=11712109356391350421&engine=google_scholar&hl=en', 'cites_id': '11712109356391350421'}, 'year': '1973'}, {'title': 'Molecular evolution and phylogenetics', 'link': 'https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=view_citation&hl=en&user=VxOmZDgAAAAJ&citation_for_view=VxOmZDgAAAAJ:YsMSGLbcyi4C', 'citation_id': 'VxOmZDgAAAAJ:YsMSGLbcyi4C', 'authors': 'M Nei, S Kumar', 'publication': 'Oxford University Press, USA, 2000', 'cited_by': {'value': 8795, 'link': 'https://scholar.google.com/scholar?oi=bibs&hl=en&cites=703217195301701212,1351927951694611906', 'serpapi_link': 'https://serpapi.com/search.json?cites=703217195301701212%2C1351927951694611906&engine=google_scholar&hl=en', 'cites_id': '703217195301701212,1351927951694611906'}, 'year': '2000'}, {'title': 'Simple methods for estimating the numbers of synonymous and nonsynonymous nucleotide substitutions.', 'link': 'https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=view_citation&hl=en&user=VxOmZDgAAAAJ&citation_for_view=VxOmZDgAAAAJ:W7OEmFMy1HYC', 'citation_id': 'VxOmZDgAAAAJ:W7OEmFMy1HYC', 'authors': 'M Nei, T Gojobori', 'publication': 'Molecular biology and evolution 3 (5), 418-426, 1986', 'cited_by': {'value': 5279, 'link': 'https://scholar.google.com/scholar?oi=bibs&hl=en&cites=12106160511321461626', 'serpapi_link': 'https://serpapi.com/search.json?cites=12106160511321461626&engine=google_scholar&hl=en', 'cites_id': '12106160511321461626'}, 'year': '1986'}, {'title': 'Prospects for inferring very large phylogenies by using the neighbor-joining method', 'link': 'https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=view_citation&hl=en&user=VxOmZDgAAAAJ&citation_for_view=VxOmZDgAAAAJ:0EnyYjriUFMC', 'citation_id': 'VxOmZDgAAAAJ:0EnyYjriUFMC', 'authors': 'K Tamura, M Nei, S Kumar', 'publication': 'Proceedings of the National Academy of Sciences 101 (30), 11030-11035, 2004', 'cited_by': {'value': 4882, 'link': 'https://scholar.google.com/scholar?oi=bibs&hl=en&cites=9650987578903829104', 'serpapi_link': 'https://serpapi.com/search.json?cites=9650987578903829104&engine=google_scholar&hl=en', 'cites_id': '9650987578903829104'}, 'year': '2004'}, {'title': 'The bottleneck effect and genetic variability in populations', 'link': 'https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=view_citation&hl=en&user=VxOmZDgAAAAJ&citation_for_view=VxOmZDgAAAAJ:eQOLeE2rZwMC', 'citation_id': 'VxOmZDgAAAAJ:eQOLeE2rZwMC', 'authors': 'M Nei, T Maruyama, R Chakraborty', 'publication': 'Evolution, 1-10, 1975', 'cited_by': {'value': 3906, 'link': 'https://scholar.google.com/scholar?oi=bibs&hl=en&cites=13149273985544466189', 'serpapi_link': 'https://serpapi.com/search.json?cites=13149273985544466189&engine=google_scholar&hl=en', 'cites_id': '13149273985544466189'}, 'year': '1975'}, {'title': 'Accuracy of estimated phylogenetic trees from molecular data', 'link': 'https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=view_citation&hl=en&user=VxOmZDgAAAAJ&citation_for_view=VxOmZDgAAAAJ:Se3iqnhoufwC', 'citation_id': 'VxOmZDgAAAAJ:Se3iqnhoufwC', 'authors': 'M Nei, F Tajima, Y Tateno', 'publication': 'Journal of molecular evolution 19 (2), 153-170, 1983', 'cited_by': {'value': 2877, 'link': 'https://scholar.google.com/scholar?oi=bibs&hl=en&cites=10638180566709737898', 'serpapi_link': 'https://serpapi.com/search.json?cites=10638180566709737898&engine=google_scholar&hl=en', 'cites_id': '10638180566709737898'}, 'year': '1983'}, {'title': 'Molecular population genetics and evolution.', 'link': 'https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=view_citation&hl=en&user=VxOmZDgAAAAJ&citation_for_view=VxOmZDgAAAAJ:WF5omc3nYNoC', 'citation_id': 'VxOmZDgAAAAJ:WF5omc3nYNoC', 'authors': 'M Nei', 'publication': 'Molecular population genetics and evolution., 1975', 'cited_by': {'value': 2795, 'link': 'https://scholar.google.com/scholar?oi=bibs&hl=en&cites=7886550802885580479', 'serpapi_link': 'https://serpapi.com/search.json?cites=7886550802885580479&engine=google_scholar&hl=en', 'cites_id': '7886550802885580479'}, 'year': '1975'}, {'title': 'Pattern of nucleotide substitution at major histocompatibility complex class I loci reveals overdominant selection', 'link': 'https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=view_citation&hl=en&user=VxOmZDgAAAAJ&citation_for_view=VxOmZDgAAAAJ:roLk4NBRz8UC', 'citation_id': 'VxOmZDgAAAAJ:roLk4NBRz8UC', 'authors': 'AL Hughes, M Nei', 'publication': 'Nature 335 (6186), 167-170, 1988', 'cited_by': {'value': 2169, 'link': 'https://scholar.google.com/scholar?oi=bibs&hl=en&cites=2966744676732650646', 'serpapi_link': 'https://serpapi.com/search.json?cites=2966744676732650646&engine=google_scholar&hl=en', 'cites_id': '2966744676732650646'}, 'year': '1988'}, {'title': 'Sampling variances of heterozygosity and genetic distance', 'link': 'https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=view_citation&hl=en&user=VxOmZDgAAAAJ&citation_for_view=VxOmZDgAAAAJ:UebtZRa9Y70C', 'citation_id': 'VxOmZDgAAAAJ:UebtZRa9Y70C', 'authors': 'M Nei, AK Roychoudhury', 'publication': 'Genetics 76 (2), 379-390, 1974', 'cited_by': {'value': 1918, 'link': 'https://scholar.google.com/scholar?oi=bibs&hl=en&cites=5978996318059495400', 'serpapi_link': 'https://serpapi.com/search.json?cites=5978996318059495400&engine=google_scholar&hl=en', 'cites_id': '5978996318059495400'}, 'year': '1974'}]
'''
```

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.